# Nest cells in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I was directed here from Stack Overflow... hope you guys can help

I have been looking into trying to nest cells in Excel, much like how the folder tree system works in File Explorer, or the folder system in Outlook.

Further examples would be having the little box with a '+' in it to expand the selection, then the '-' to contract. I've searched Google to look for any help but couldn't really find anything, perhaps this means it cannot be done but thought I'd ask here to get some expert advice.

Thanks

Someone in Stack Overflow mentioned Outlines, which I'm currently looking at

EDIT: Outlines worked perfectly.

Comment: Hello Ben, if you have found a solution to this question, please post it as an answer and accept it, for future visitors.

Comment: You could have asked a moderator to migrate your question to here by raising a flag on it over there. That way, we retain the responses. Remember that these sites are meant as a reference for other people to use not just the person that asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Select the rows you want to nest together and then, in the Data ribbon, click Group.

[image: Screenshot 1]

A new column appears to the left of the row headers. Clicking the `-` collapses the rows. Clicking the `+` expands the rows.

[image: Screenshot 2]      [image: Screenshot 3]